# Teredata: create violatile table xxx on commit delete rows;begin transaction, end transaction, no return

Tags: teradata

```
create volatile table product (product_id integer , product_name varchar(10), category varchar(10))  on commit delete rows;

begin transaction ;

insert into product (product_id,product_name,category) values(122, 'chair', 'furniture');
sel * from product;
end transaction;
```

I'm wondering why output is nothing? How to modify the queries to get inserted values?

Comment: Having actually read your complete post, I can't reproduce that behavior. Are you sure you aren't running your select after the end transaction?

Comment: I vaguely remember something about [Teradata vs ANSI session modes](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/V0f5TNULG3KyqagJFs3fJA/RbjKBm2cQznHptvPyUPFOw) possibly having an effect on this.

Comment: That tool are you using to submit this SQL to the database, and what driver does it use? Do you get an error on the END TRANSACTION statement?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm sure I was running select before end transaction. There is no error. Just nothing like the table is empty.

Comment: Are you using SQL Assistant, bteq,?

Comment: You probably run Teradata Studio using a Teradata mode session. In a TMODE=TERA session the JDBC driver inserts BT/ET automatically, no matter if you check or uncheck "Autocommit", there's no real control anymore. When I complaint the answer was, no bug, "works as designed" :-(

Answer (score 0):

There may be several problems with starting a transaction:

1. check if you are using your connection configuration:
   Session Mode: Teradata
2. add a database name before the product table name. 
   It is possible that your user has no free space for records.
3. in my Teradata SQL Assistant, the word product is highlighted, and check if the word "product" is not reserved in your Teradata database configuration.

   SELECT * FROM SYSLIB.SQLRestrictedWords;